# How Hibernate Batch insert works?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, batch-insert, hibernate-batch-updates

Can some one explain me how

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 1000
```

and

```
if (i % 100 == 0 && i > 0) {
    session.flush();
    session.clear();
}
```

together works?

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html

Comment: @soorapadman , Thanks for the article  .. But what if hibernate.jdbc.batch_size is different from my flushing loop ?

Answer (score 9):

Hibernate property `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` is a way for hibernate to optimize your insert or update statetment whereas flushing loop is about memory exhaustion.

Without batchsize when you try to save an entity hibernate fire 1 insert statement, thus if you work with a big collection, for each save hibernate fire 1 statement.

Imagine the following chunk of code :

```
for (Entity e : entities) {
    session.save(e);
}
```

Here hibernate will fire 1 insert statement per entity in your collection.  if you have 100 elements in your collection so 100 insert statements will be fire.
This approach is not very efficient for 2 main reasons:

- 1. You increase exponentially your 1st level cache and you'll probably finish soon with an `OutOfMemoryException`.
- 2. You degrade performance due to network round trip for each statement.

`hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` and the flushing loop have 2 differents purposes but are complementary.

Hibernate use the first to control how many entities will be in batch. Under the cover Hibernate use `java.sql.Statement.addBatch(...)` and `executeBatch()` methods.

So `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` tells hibernate how many times it have to call `addBatch()` before calling `executeBatch()`.

*So setting this property doesn't prevent you of memory exhaution.*

In order to take care of the memory you have to flush your session on a regular basis and this is the purpose of flushing loop.

When you write:

```
for (Entity e : entities) {
    if (i % 100 == 0 && i > 0) {
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}
```

you're telling hibernate to flush and clear the session every 100 entities (you release memory).

**So now what is the link between the 2 ?**

In order to be optimal you have to define your `jdbc.batch_size` and your flushing param identical.

if you define a flush param lower that the batch_size you choose so hibernate will flush the session more frequently so it will create small batch until it arrive to batch size, which is not efficient.

when the 2 are the same hibernate will only execute batches of optimal size except for the last one if size of collection is not a multiple of your batch_size.

You can see the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417977/why-number-of-objects-being-flushed-should-be-equal-to-hibernate-jdbc-batch-size) for more details about this last point.

Comment: What about other requirements such as id generation strategy limitations?

Comment: by *and your flushing param identical* does that mean that I have to do `session.flush()` every 50 persists? Can I wait untill the very end of the whole process to do `flush()`?

Answer (score 1):

`hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` determines the **maximum** batch size that is executed. If implicit or explicit flush is performed before the specified batch size is reached (the number of pending insert or update statements for [the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35794220/4754790)), all pending statements are packed in one batch, and the 'accumulation' of statements is restarted.

So, in your example you would execute batches consisting of 100 statements each. Or, for example, if the batch size were 100 and the modulo divider were 500, when the flush operation occurs you would execute 5 batches consisting of 100 statements each.

Answer (score 0):

Batch Processing allows you to group related SQL statements into a batch and submit them with one call to the database.

**Why we need**

It is important to keep in mind, that each update added to a Statement or PreparedStatement is executed separately by the database. That means, that some of them may succeed before one of them fails. All the statements that have succeeded are now applied to the database, but the rest of the updates may not be. This can result in an inconsistent data in the database.

To avoid this, you can execute the batch update inside a transaction. When executed inside a transaction you can make sure that either all updates are executed, or none are. Any successful updates can be rolled back, in case one of the updates fail.

**What is Batch and Flushing**

Batch size and flushing is different thing. when you set `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` to `1000` it means hibernate will do  batch inserts or update upto `1000` entities.`flush` operation can be used the write all changes to the database before the transaction is committed

if your batch size is set to 1000, and you flush every 100 entity, Hibernate will execute lots of small batches of 100 insert or update  statements for 10 times.

Please read more below this link:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html

[Why number of objects being flushed should be equal to hibernate.jdbc.batch_size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417977/why-number-of-objects-being-flushed-should-be-equal-to-hibernate-jdbc-batch-size)