# how to configure spring boot and data jpa for batch insert

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot  and spring data jpa with hibernate, `japrepository.save(List)` took 20 minutes to save 8000 records to oracle database. can some one help me how to solve it. Adding `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=1000` in application.properties also didn't help.

application.properties

```
server.servlet-path = /*         
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/mydatasource       
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true         
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1 
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10g‌​Dialect 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=1000
```

Comment: Do you have primary key generation with GeneratedValue? And if yes what strategy

Comment: @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ubseq")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "OWNER.ub_seq", schema = "OWNER",  allocationSize = 1, name = "ubseq")

 private long id;

Comment: The problem could be the allocationSize of your Sequence because for every insert it will get a new sequence number that is a expensive operation. Is there a reason for having it set to 1?

Comment: No  specific reason, actually I m not very familiar with Spring/Hibernate frameworks.  I need the primary key value from a sequence, or if you could suggest something else will try.

Comment: great, I just removed 'allocationSize = 1' attribute from SequenceGenerator and all 8000 records got saved in 1 min. Initially I thought it is same like increment by one.  Now my code is working in Tomcat ,  I need to actually deploy it on JBoss, lets see how it works. Many thanks Simon Martinelli :)

Comment: Great! I posted this a the answer. Please flag the answer as correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem could be the allocationSize of your Sequence because for every insert it will get a new sequence number that is a expensive operation.

If you can set the allocationSize to a higher value that works for your case.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a reasonable batch_size like 50 or 30. In addition to that try to set the parameter

`spring.jpa.hibernate.order_inserts=true 
spring.jpa.hibernate.order_updates=true`

So the inserts and updates are ordered before sending to database. Also look here [Spring Boot JPA Bulk insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632045/spring-boot-jpa-bulk-insert) or https://memorynotfound.com/hibernate-jpa-batch-insert-batch-update-example/

For further examples and details.

Comment: I tried adding                       spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=100
spring.jpa.hibernate.order_inserts=true 
spring.jpa.hibernate.order_updates=true           it alone didn't solve the issue but these configureations also need along removing 'allocation size' from SequenceGenerator.           Thanks Francesco