# Spring Boot MySQL not batching inserts

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I've applied pretty much all solutions posted here on SO regarding this issue but nothing worked.

My **application.properties**:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?logger=com.mysql.jdbc.log.Slf4JLogger&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&profileSQL=true&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=secret
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 100
spring.jpa.hibernate.order_inserts   = true 
spring.jpa.hibernate.order_updates   = true

logging.level.root=info
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %highlight(%-5p) %gray(%c{0}::%M) - %m%n
```

My **EntityRepository**:

```
@Repository
public interface EntityRepository extends CrudRepository<Entity, Long> { }
```

My **Entity**:

```
@Data @Entity
public class Entity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
  private Long id;

  private Long attr;

}
```

And the simplified code that calls repository:

```
int batchSize = 100;
List<Entity> batchEntities = new ArrayList<>();
for(Entity entity : entities) {
  batchEntities.add(entity);
  if(batchEntities.size() >= batchSize) {
    entityRepository.saveAll(batchEntities);
    batchEntities.clear();
  }
}
```

What I've done:

As per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530112/no-matter-what-i-cant-batch-mysql-insert-statements-in-hibernate) I've enabled the `profileSQL=true` option and the log produces several individual inserts. Also, I've enabled global logging on SQL server and it too produces sequence of individual inserts.

As per [this another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632045/spring-boot-jpa-bulk-insert) and [yet another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772230/how-to-do-bulk-multi-row-inserts-with-jparepository) I've made sure that `batch_size` is set in the `application.properties` file and although I have no parent-child relationship I've also tried to use the `order_inserts` and `order_updates`. Also, I've enabled the `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` option and use the `saveAll(...)` method.

I've also tried to ditch the premade `CrudRepository` and my a custom one, by flushing after every `batchSize`-th persist.

Nothing above helped.

Comment: `spring.jpa.hibernate.order_updates` won't do anything (the same applies to the other properties). Instead use `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates` (same applies to the other custom hibernate properties as well).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you! It works now perfectly. Can't believe I've missed that. Would you like to rewrite your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following properties don't exists in Spring Boot.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 100
spring.jpa.hibernate.order_inserts   = true 
spring.jpa.hibernate.order_updates   = true
```

To add custom properties use the `spring.jpa.properties` prefix instead.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 100
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts   = true 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates   = true
```

Should do the trick.

See also the Spring Boot documentation on [how to configure JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-jpa-properties).